# IBM MQ- Create a new local definition of remote queue

Tags: ibm-mq, messaging

Current setup is QM1 (queue manager 1) is having local definition Q1 (mq 1). On QM2, Q1 is configured as remote queue. This configuration works fine. That means any app connecting to QM2 can use name  Q1 and those messages gets forwarded to QM1 through distributed Mq setup(channels, transmit queues).

I want to know if I create new Q1 as local queue on QM2 , will mqput calls forward messages to both Queues?

Comment: Queue names are unique in a queue manager. You can't have two queues with same name, one pointing to a local queue and another to remote queue.

Comment: Correct. You can't have the same queue object name, irrespective of the flavor of the queue object type which could be local queue, remote queue, alias queue etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot issue 1 MQPUT and have the message go to more than 1 queue unless you have configured a distribution list or configured the queue to be under Pub/Sub but not all fields of the MQMD are copied.

If you want to replicate messages (for a backup or SLA mechanism) including the MQMD fields then you need to look at a product like [MQ Message Replication](https://capitalware.com/mqmr_overview.html).